# Microsoft Officeなしでhtmlをxls形式に変換したい

Tags: excel

.NET Framework3.5を使用しています。

対象のプログラムはMicrosoft. Interop. Excel .dllを用いてHtml形式ファイルをXls形式ファイルに変換しているのですが、対象の顧客環境にExcelがインストールされているにも関わらず、制限がかけられているのか、dllからExcelを呼び出せない状態が続いています。
Excelがインストールされていないかのような動作をします。

現状、上記の調査が難航しているため、上記dllを用いて動作環境にインストールされているExcelの機能を使わずに、Htmlをxlsに変換する方法を調査しているのですが、サンプル等ご存じないでしょうか。
以下の様なことをプログラムを使わずにExcelを使用すれば可能なのですが、これをNPOI等のサードパーティ製のプログラムを使って、Excelがインストールされていなくてもxlsを出力できる状態にしたいのです。htmlが生成できるまでは対象顧客環境でも検証できています。

1. htmlの拡張子をxlsに変更
2. ダブルクリックして警告を無視してExcelで開く
3. シート名をSheet1に変更
4. シートの特定の列にドロップダウンリストで特定の値のリストを埋め込み
5. 名前を付けて保存して、xlsとして保存

サンプルコード等あれば教えていただけないでしょうか。NPOIでなくても構いません。

Comment: 試したわけではありません。Excelで「マクロを記録する」を実行すればVBAのコードが得られますので、このコードを参考にVB.NETやC#のコードを作成してはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: akira ejiriさんがご指摘の通りなんですが、ちょっと補足です。「マクロ記録」を実行すると、「記録終了」を選択するまでのExcel操作が全てマクロコマンドとして記録されていきます。それを基に、NPOIなどに移植していくのが一般的だと思います。それでどうしても実現できない部分が出てきたら改めてご質問されたら良いと思います。

Comment: Office 2007からxlsx形式が導入されていますが、そうではなくOffice 2003以前のxls形式が求められているのでしょうか？

Comment: akira ejiri様 Sugiyama Koichi様　　ご説ごもっともです。改めてやってみてから質問いたします。

Comment: sayuri様 はい、対象のプログラムはレガシーコードで、xls形式ファイルからデータを取得、そして同様のxls形式ファイルで出力する必要があります。

Comment: xlsからデータを取り込むときにはMicrosoft.Jet.OLEDBでデータを取り込んでいるのでExcelは不要なのですが、xlsを生成するときにはまずhtmlを生成してから上記のような処理をしているので、環境にExcelがいる仕様になっているようです。

Comment: 1)html ファイルの拡張子を xls に変更して それを警告を無視してエクセルで開く。という部分が 謎すぎて 誰も正しい回答が出せないと思います。 この html をテキストエディタで開いたら実は CSV形式だった という事はありませんか？

Comment: illuminate33さの質問は私も興味があり、答えが知りたいと思いました。自己解決した場合でも自己回答を投稿してほいいと思います。VBAのコードを機械的に単純にVB.NETに変換するのは（有償のサービスがあるぐらいですから）簡単ではないと考えています。変換元の具体例や記録したマクロのコードが質問内容に含まれていれば、具体的な回答が得られると思います。

Comment: EXCELを起動してHTMLファイルを開くのが面倒なので、HTMLファイルの拡張子を`.xls`に変え、EXCELをHTMLビューアとして使うのは常套手段だと思います。

Comment: akira ejiri様のおっしゃる通り拡張子を変えればExcelでhtmlファイルをダブルクリックで開くことができます。当件に関心を持っていただいてありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

有償ですが [Aspose.Cells for .NET](https://products.aspose.com/cells/net) は、`html`から`.xls`への変換が可能です。どの程度複雑なhtmlかは分かりませんが、試してみると良いかと思います。

```cs
using System.IO;

using Aspose.Cells;
using System;

namespace Aspose.Cells.Examples.CSharp.Files.Handling
{
    public class OpeningHTMLFile
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            // ExStart:1
            // The path to the documents directory.
            string dataDir = RunExamples.GetDataDir(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);


            string filePath = dataDir + "Book1.html";

            // Instantiate LoadOptions specified by the LoadFormat.
            HtmlLoadOptions loadOptions = new HtmlLoadOptions(LoadFormat.Html);

            // Create a Workbook object and opening the file from its path
            Workbook wb = new Workbook(filePath, loadOptions);
            // Save the MHT file
            wb.Save(filePath + "output.xlsx");
            // ExEnd:1
        }
    }
}
```

[.NET Framework 3.5 にも対応](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/System+Requirements)しているようです。

Comment: htb様 情報ありがとうございます。ライセンス的に対象顧客で使用可能か確認させてください。

Comment: そのコメントは質問ですか？

Comment: 対象顧客がどんなものか私には知る由も無いので、ご自身で判断してください。
 https://www.xlsoft.com/jp/products/aspose/license_types.html

Comment: 紛らわしい書き方をして申し訳ありません。ライセンスに関しては頂いたサイトを調べます。ありがとうございます。